# Remote pc desktop from android device development

Tags: android, remote-desktop

I'm trying to develop an android app with remote access functions. I have been searching similar posts about how remote desktop is made and what is the most efficient method, but i haven't found too mutch information about this.

Now i'm trying to send screenshots and display each one on a ImageView. It works, but the ImageView doesn't get refreshed until the app has ended. I tried to use `postInvalidate()` and `invalidate()` on an `AsyncTask`, but it didn't work.

I'd also like to know if there is a better way (or even different ways) to develop a remote desktop app. I wanna do it by myself, so i don't want to use any app as TeamViewer or similar.

Thanks for the help. Here is my code:

**Client**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static Button boton;
static byte[] imagen;
static ImageView imagenVista;
static Bitmap bmp;
static Socket clientSocket;
static OutputStream os;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(evento);
    imagenVista = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}

private OnClickListener evento = new OnClickListener() {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (boton.getText().equals("Start")){
            boton.setText("Stop");

            try{                       
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                }                                       

                while(true){

                    Socket clientSocket= new Socket();                  
                    InetSocketAddress addr=new InetSocketAddress("10.209.0.93", 5555);
                    clientSocket.connect(addr);
                    OutputStream os=clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    os.write("capture".getBytes());
                    ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                    construyendo_img(entrada)
                    new TareaSegundoPlano().doInBackground(entrada);

                     entrada.close();
                     os.flush();
                     clientSocket.close();                                              
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

        else{
            boton.setText("Start");
        }
    }
};

public void construyendo_img(ObjectInputStream entrada)throws IOException,      ClassNotFoundException{       

      byte[] bytes_img = (byte[]) entrada.readObject();
      ByteArrayInputStream entrada_img = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes_img);

      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes_img, 0, bytes_img.length);
      imagenVista.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}

public class TareaSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask<Void, ObjectInputStream, Void>{                 
        protected void onPreExecute(){}  

        protected Void doInBackground(ObjectInputStream... params) {                
            imagenVista.invalidate();               
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }    
    }
}
```